# What does "forgive/aphes" mean in Matthew 6:12?

Tags: greek, matthew

**Matthew 6:12**

> "and **forgive** us our debts, as we also have forgiven our debtors". ESV

ἄφες/"aphes"/forgive:  Why is "aphes" 2nd aorist, imperative?

What meaning does it thus convey?

Answer (score 1):

**ἀφίημι (aphiemi) Tense**

First note that in the clause of Matt 6:12, both occurrences of the verb ἀφίημι are in the same verb tense - aorist active (the first is imperative mood and the second is indicative mood).  Many versions try to translate the second as though it is a perfect tense (we have forgiven) or similar.

**ἀφίημι (aphiemi) Meaning**

BDAG supplies the meaning in this verse:

2. **to release from legal or moral obligation or consequence, *cancel, remit, pardon***, eg, Luke 7:41, 11:4, 5:20, 23, 1 John 1:9, Matt 6:14, Mark 11:25, etc.

That is, to forgive debts is to cancel the debt.  Jesus emphasized the point that God forgives to the extent that we forgive in the parable of Matt 18:21-35 - the unforgiving servant.

Comment: 2 "forgives" in this verse. What is the first one conveying as an imperative? Something certain? Something about the future? A continuation?

Comment: Imperative mood is an order like, "Left turn!", "Go home!", etc.  The second indicative mood is a simple statement of fact like, "My car is red".

Comment: Sorry but I am still unsure. What is the effect of the first "forgive" being a 2nd aorist?

Comment: @C.Stroud - aorist is simply a tense denoting an action which is the action generally - it does not refer specifically to past, present or future, it is simply the action.  In this way, it encompasses all forgiveness of all sins, past present and future.

Comment: In your answer you don't mention "past present and future" which you do mention in your comment. I am not sure quite how it fits in your answer.

Comment: @C.Stroud - that is bound up with the normal meaning of "aorist" - see you usual dictionary.